# MS-Access 2007: Query for names that have two or more different values in another field

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hello & thank you in advance.

I have an access db that has the following information about mammals we captured. Each capture has a unique ID, which is the capture table's primary key: "capture_id". The mammals (depending on species) have ear tags that we use to track them from year to year and day to day. These are in a field called "id_code". I have the sex of the mammal as it was recorded at capture time in another field called sex.

I want a query that will return all instances of an id_code IF the sex changes even once for that id.

Example: Animal E555 was caught 4 times, 3 times someone recorded this animal as a F and once as a M.

I've managed to get it to display this info by stacking about 5 queries on top of each other (Query for recaptured animals -> Query for all records of animals from 1st query -> Query for unique combo of id & sex (via just using those two columns & requiring "Unique Values") -> Query that pulls only duplicate id values from that last one and pulls back up all capture records of those ids). HOwever, this is clearly not the right way to do this, it is then not updateable (which I need since this is for data quality control) and for some reason it also returns duplicates of each of those records...

I realize that this could be solved two other ways:

- Using R to pull up these records (I want none of this data to have to leave the database though, because we're working on getting it into one place after 35 years of collecting! And my boss can't use R and I'm seasonal, so I want him to just have to open a query)
- Creating a table that tracks all animal id's as an animal index. However, this would make entering the data more difficult and also require someone to go back through 20,000 records and create a brand new animal id for every one because you can't give ear tags to voles & things so they don't get a unique identifier in the field.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple to do with a single query. As a bonus, the query will be updatable, not duplicated, and simple to use:

```
SELECT mammals.ID, mammals.Sex, mammals.id_code, mammals.date_recorded
FROM mammals
WHERE mammals.id_code In 
 (select id_code from 
  (select distinct id_code, sex from [mammals]) a 
  group by id_code 
  having count(*)>1
 );
```

The reason why you see a sub-query inside a sub-query is because Access does not support `COUNT(DISTINCT)`. With any other "normal" database you would write:

```
SELECT mammals.ID, mammals.Sex, mammals.id_code, mammals.date_recorded
FROM mammals
WHERE mammals.id_code In 
 (select id_code
  from [mammals]
  group by id_code 
  having count(DISTINCT Sex)>1
 );
```

Comment: This looks great! I will try it tomorrow when I open the db! I knew it had to be something with nesting that select query into the other one, but I don't really know sql well enough to figure it out. Thank you!